# Java/Scala Regex: Move number in parentheses in string

Tags: java, regex, scala, replace, regex-group

How can I capture the number (250 in the following case) and insert it in the replacement string?

What I have: `"CHAR () FOR BIT DATA(250) NOT NULL"`

What I want: `"CHAR (250) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL"`

I'm looking to do this in Scala, but I guess it simply uses `java.util.regex`.

Here's what I've tried:

`"""CHAR () FOR BIT DATA(250) NOT NULL""".replaceAll("CHAR \\(\\) FOR BIT DATA\\(([0-9]+)\\)", "Here is the string: $0")`

I simply don't know how to get only the digits to re-insert them in a new string.

Comment: To escape parentheses in regex, you'll need a backslash (and an extra backslash for your Java/Scala string). Otherwise, it's recognized as a group. Also, I think you want `$1` instead of `$0`, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
.replaceAll("""(CHAR \()(\) FOR BIT DATA)\((\d+)\)""", "$1$3$2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TPFWoO/1)

**Details**

- `(CHAR \()` - Group 1 (`$1`): `CHAR (` text
- `(\) FOR BIT DATA)` - Group 2 (`$2`): `) FOR BIT DATA` text
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 3 (`$3`): one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the following, but your solution works beautifully. `"""CHAR () FOR BIT DATA(250) NOT NULL""".replaceAll("CHAR \\(\\) FOR BIT DATA\\(([0-9]+)\\) NOT NULL", "CHAR ($1) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL")`